# Got 504 Timeout in 200ms. What does that mean?

Tags: nginx, timeout, springframework, 504

I have a website. Using Nginx and Spring. Today, some of APIs got 504 gateway timeout, but these time-out return instantly. I suppose a time-out error should be returned after a period of time. So, what does this mean?